# Simple state service unwanted complexity

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to make a simple service to manage a single state in my application: the visibility of a loader.

The changes will be emitted by some components and the main layout component will subscribe it to watch for boolean change. It's then handled by a simple `ngIf`.

Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AppLoaderService {
  private isLoaderVisible = new Subject<boolean>();

  changeLoaderState = this.isLoaderVisible.asObservable();

  emitChange(state: any) {
    this.isLoaderVisible.next(state);
  }

}
```

Is my method for creating this simple service introducing too much complexity for a simple toggler?

**Are the use of `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` relevant in my case?** I found some information about the necessity to use them when we want to emit such changes or set a default value at service init (`BehaviorSubject`).

But maybe a simple `Observable` could be sufficient here, but how to deal with value change emit?

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you are serving is a simple `*ngIf`, I see no use for `Subject` and `Observable`. You can just use a simple `boolean` value as property of the service. Maybe a getter and a setter, but I wouldn't make it that complex with Observables if you have no dependencies which have to react on a change of visibility.

Comment: Will my layout component, using this boolean, be able to detect change an this simple boolean? Doesn't it need to subscribe to any value (such observable) to trigger change detection?

Comment: Yes, because if you change that variable, you are most likely working in the so called `zone`. This is the beauty of angular. You can just change variables, and the template reacts immediately. This is of course if you use the default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a boolean if all you want is to display a loader and it is much simpler.

```
public isLoaderVisible:boolean=false;
```

Let's say in your component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private loaderService: AppLoaderService 
  ){}
...
```

And in your component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loaderService.isLoaderVisible">
  <!-- do something here -->
```